# finding the minimum using map reduce

Tags: python, mapreduce

Im trying to find the minimum of data set and was given this example to help. The code gives me the maximum. I cant find what to change to make it find the min.

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob

from mrjob.step import MRStep

class HighestRevenue(MRJob):

    def mapper_get_city(self, key, line):
        # create a key-value pair with key: city and value: amount
        line_cols = line.split(',')
        yield line_cols[0], float(line_cols[2])

    def combiner_process_city(self, city, amount):
        # consolidates all key-value pairs of mapper function (performed at mapper nodes)
        yield city, sum(amount)

    def reducer_city_amount(self, city, amount):
        # final consolidation of key-value pairs at reducer nodes
        yield None, (city, sum(amount))

    def secondReducer(self, city, amount):
        self.aList = []
        for a in amount:
            self.aList.append(a)
        self.aList.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
        for m in range(0,1):
            yield self.aList[0]

    def steps(self):
        return [
            MRStep(mapper = self.mapper_get_city,
                    combiner = self.combiner_process_city,
                    reducer = self.reducer_city_amount),
            MRStep(reducer = self.secondReducer)
             ]
```

Comment: There is a good answer already. Just wanted to point out that in the future you might want to format your code in a nice way. And also try to post the minimal code snippet that is a working example, but can be understood very fast. These will increase the willingness of users to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `reverse=True` from `sort` procedure inside of `secondReducer`

Comment: ty that solve the problem I was having. I assume that reverse statement just took the result as opposite.